# Why false is displayed on status bar of safari browser?

Tags: safari, statusbar

I am using safari 3.2 and 4.0.3. On the status bar, false is displayed. Even when my site is loading, the same message is displayed: false. Can anyone suggest what the problem might be and the solution as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which site does this happen with?

Comment: Thanks Dave! Its not live yet, so unable to give link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the page has some javascript that does the equivalent of

```
window.status = false;
```

Comment: Once again thank you so much Dave. Actually, there was var status defined in the js fil. I just renamed the variable and it worked.